# how to play mp3 sound from server on swift4?

Tags: audio, swift4

I have test this func, the error is like below :

```
playSound(soundUrl: "httpwebxxxxxxxx/sound2.mp3")

func playSound(soundUrl: String) {
        let sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundUrl)
        do {
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }catch let error {
            print(soundUrl)
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            //Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
        }
    }
```

I have tested on realy device iphone 5 ios 10.3 and on simulator too

Answer (score 0):

The initializer `fileURLWithPath` of URL is only for URLs in the local file system, for a remote URL you have to use the API

```
let sound = URL(string: soundUrl)
```

Basically don't load data synchronously from a remote URL. `Use URLSession / URLSessionDataTask`.